# Is my OptionMenu visible (I want to close it after 2 minutes)

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I want to close an Options Menu 2 minutes after it is activated. The reason is the app is for elderly and disabled people who cannot be relied on to touch the screen to close it themselves!

The onCreateOptionMenu method is called during the Activity onCreate. There seems to be no obvious way to catch that the menu is being displayed.

Comment: Change 10s to 2 min and you are done https://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/progamatically-open-and-close-an-activitys-option-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

"Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown."

And then `closeOptionsMenu()` to close it programmatically.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#closeOptionsMenu()

Here's a quick example with the timeout reduced to 10 seconds for testing purposes:

```
public class MainActivity6 extends Activity {
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable menuCloser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler();
        menuCloser = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                closeOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("test");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(menuCloser);
        handler.postDelayed(menuCloser, 10000);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Strangely enough I tried a solution using the `onOptionsMenuClosed()` callback first to remove queued `menuCloser` when the menu has been closed, but the callback is never called.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsMenuClosed(android.view.Menu)), it probably should be:

"This hook is called whenever the options menu is being closed (either by the user canceling (sic!) the menu with the back/menu button, or when an item is selected)."

More importantly for you possibly, this does not seem to work at all using the `ActionBarActivity` from the support library. The `Runnable` executes and calls `closeOptionsMenu()` but the menu is not closed. (`onOptionsMenuClosed()` isn't called either, no matter how the menu is closed.)

You might have some luck trying the new `AppCompatActivity`, but I haven't been able to test that yet.

Comment: Thank you very much.  So far so good!. I can trigger a closeOptionsMenu() correctly, but it does not actually work, that is to say, it executes by the Menu remains visible. I even tried getWindow().closePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL); stil shows the menu

Comment: @user462990 I've added an example to my answer. Can you add some code you tried to your question so we can see what the issue might be? Also note that I had no luck getting this to work with the ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about the ActionBarActivity, which my app is. 
*You say...More importantly for you possibly, this does not seem to work at all using the ActionBarActivity from the support library. The Runnable executes and calls closeOptionsMenu() but the menu is not closed. (onOptionsMenuClosed() isn't called either, no matter how the menu is closed.)*

My code is quite straightforward (if idiosyncratic)...

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Close the menu after a period of time.
        addActionQueueUnique(new TimeAction(20,TimeAction.CLOSE_OPTION_MENU ,"close menu"));
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

and to catch it using my own timer loop

```
case TimeAction.CLOSE_OPTION_MENU:
                Logd("in TimeAction.CLOSE_OPTION_MENU ");
                activity.closeOptionsMenu();
                //getWindow().closePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);
                break;
```

the message in teh Logd appears at the expected place in teh log, but the menu does not close.
I'll probably wait until the programmers at Google fix this, the code should work when the underlying code is corrected.

Thanks for your help